# Converting UNIX to HH-MM-SS Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, unix, datetime-conversion

I am trying to conver unix timestamp to a readable time. I have tried all solutions I can find, none still work. I do not want to use any modules or frameworks. Id appreciate some help converting.(Angular) Please dont link to other questions. ive read them all. Thnk you

```
  var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
  console.log(unix) //works


  function secondstotime(unix)
{
    var t = new Date(1970,0,1);
    t.setSeconds(unix);
    var s = t.toTimeString().substr(0,8);
    if(unix > 86399)
      s = Math.floor((t - Date.parse("1/1/70")) / 3600000) + s.substr(2);
    console.log(s);
} 
secondstotime();
```

Comment: secondstotime(unix); , try like this

Answer (score 2):

In angularjs you can simply use date filter to convert Unix timestamp (seconds). You just need to multiply Unix timestamp by 1000 to make it milliseconds timestamp. Here is the code

```
<p>{{1469424998 * 1000 | date:'hh:mm:ss'}}</p>
```

or you can use some external library like mommentjs to convert Unix Timestamp (seconds) to datetime like this

```
 var day = moment.unix(1469424998);
console.log(day.format("hh:mm:ss"));
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear. In your current code, it prints following output:

```
1469424998
Invalid
```

It prints `Invalid` because you are missing parameter of `secondstotime()` method. If you add paameters to `secondstotime()` method call, it will print following output:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uh8qy5wz/)

```
var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
  console.log(unix) //works


  function secondstotime(unix)
  {
    var t = new Date(1970,0,1);
    t.setSeconds(unix);
    var s = t.toTimeString().substr(0,8);
    if(unix > 86399)
      s = Math.floor((t - Date.parse("1/1/70")) / 3600000) + s.substr(2);
    console.log(s);
 } 
 secondstotime(unix);
```

Output:

```
1469424875
56408173:34:35
```

It is not clear what you exactly want. Can you show us your expected output?